# Mesh not rendering correctly with geometry nodes

Tags: rendering

I have made this cell fracture with geometry nodes, I have set camera to render it, it’s rendering the angle but not the actual fractured mesh. Even if I remove the keyframes its rendering just the block mesh.

Thank you.

[image]

[image]

Comment: i am sorry, but i can only vote to close this question because we have no idea how your node tree looks like or your render settings or your animation.

Comment: Hi, @blender breath. Please edit this to give us a clue. By screwing my eyes up, on your top image, I can _just_ tell from the Outliner that 'Cube' carries modifiers and is marked visible in viewport but non-rendering.. does that have anything to do with it? If not, maybe best to share on https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: I figured it out, you can close the question. Thank you.